# old 2009 iMac 27" grey boot screen & black screen

Tags: macos, boot, mac, hardware-failure

Sorry for the premature question posting; as explored in the comments, the problem manifested itself again by the screen going blank shortly after writing this post. **Symptoms persisting after downgrading sort of burst the bubble on my theory of a software problem, and the more i read online the more it looked like a hardware issue.** It's now 2 years later, and after having this computer sitting around my office, and not getting around to fixing it, I am thinking of junking it(and maybe trying to save the lcd). The closest i got to fixing it was watching some youtube videos like these:

[apple imac black screen of death ( late 2009 i3 3.06ghz )](https://youtu.be/GUc6UefiELQ)

[Late 2009 iMac 27" Video Card Repair — 4850 — 2nd Bake](https://youtu.be/6BJGLFCigdA)

...Supposedly you can fix the gpu in your oven, although it seemed like a big job i decided the problem was beyond me. ...and computers do get old and need to be replaced from time to time, so I guess this will just be mystery left unsolved(though I'm very suspicious of the graphics card).

## I'm leaving the original question below:

Last summer I acquired an Apple iMac 27" late 2009 model EMC 2309. It was being thrown out because it was no longer able to boot(**would not pass the grey screen**), and the owner decided to buy a newer one. The computer's death was not sudden, but rather became gradually worse over time, where more and more frequently the **screen would suddenly go black**, requiring reboot. However **it was not until the previous owner tried to install High Sierra that the iMac died completely**. I heard through the grapevine that this is a common problem with that vintage, and it was explained as the result of hardware failure in the graphics card, due to general old age...

I was not really satisfied with that explanation, and it didn't really seam right to me, so I decided to downgrade to Snow Leopard, and viola it booted and functioned normally. Since then **I have upgraded to Mavericks and everything seems to be running fine**. Safari is stuck on 7.0, but it turns out it will run Firefox 66.0, and many other apps that still support Mavericks.

I don't know what is more troubling, that someone would try to upgrade that old hardware to 10.13, or that the upgrade was done through the AppStore. What I am wondering is, since there is clearly nothing wrong with the hardware, **why would Apple post an upgrade in the AppStore that will totally not work on your computer?** Shouldn't there be some sort of supported-hardware list?

**Is this something special to this model? This computer? I suspect it's a similar story for other ~10 year old Apples.**

Things seam to be running smoothly now. Should I risk going up to Yosemite? Remember, it was not until Sierra that problems really started occurring. **What features added in El Capitan and Sierra could be the cause of this problem?**

Comment: Your third paragraph is problematic. You're asserting as fact that Apple is offering non-working software. The fact it didn't work in your case (plus whatever the grapevine has to say) amounts to less than convincing proof this is actually the case.

Comment: Could be the case.

Answer (score 2):

"Should I risk it?" Yes.
The OS you are currently on is no longer secure. It's the equivalent of still running Windows Vista.
Though you will find newer OSes will tend to slow the machine down, as they are geared towards SSD rather than HD, there is nothing inherently unstable about running High Sierra on an 09 machine. I have one here, doing just fine.

You will get best mileage out of the machine by installing an SSD; other than that it should be fine & dandy on High Sierra.

The only way to not quite prove, but add weight to your theory would be to start from Snow Leopard, then jump via El Capitan [essential first step] to High Sierra, without installing any non-Apple software at all.
Then test.
Belt & braces would be to clone the boot partition at each step so you can go back over old territory should you find a 'sticking point'.

To eliminate it being a hardware fault, you should be able to find the Apple Hardware Test on disk two of the Snow Leopard CDs, iirc.
Note also that a flat PRAM battery can cause all kinds of random, seemingly unrelated issues. [iFixit has repair & teardown guides](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/iMac_Intel_27%22_EMC_2309_and_2374).

Comment: Bold & unsupported sweeping statements like "why would Apple post an upgrade in the AppStore that will totally not work on your computer?" will attract down- & close-votes more than anything else. Presumably you have nuked & paved this machine to make it "yours" so any prior virus scan would be irrelevant.

Comment: Railing against close or down votes is a bit pointless - those people have been & gone; you are unlikely to see them return to change their minds - the anonymity of the interweb :\

Comment: Alright, I went through my notes: this actually happened in March 2018. There was no virus; I had installed Malwarebytes prior to DriveGenius, and the virus scan showed [a false positive related to RTProtectionDaemon](https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/206796-is-rtprotectiondaemon-a-legit-part-of-malwarebytes/). I still don't know why my iMac died, but it works now on Mavericks! I've sort of repurposed it at this point, and people like Firefox are nice enough to publish software support back that far. perhaps I will test it later further, although it requires doing some backups first.

Comment: Because Apple don't charge for upgrades & businesses don't hang onto macOS versions like they do with Windows; so they support the last 3 major revisions; which, combined with what OS will run on which machine, gives each machine 10 years' support. Personally I think that's a better policy for the end user.